# Unable to get value (email) from dictionary in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

```
OrderedDict([('first_name', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f9b5bed4c50>), ('last_name', <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7f9b3b7abf50>), ('email', <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x7f9b3b7abf10>)])
```

I am a new programmer in Python/Django, and I neeed a bit a of help.

I have this dictionnary, when I called `self.fields`. I am trying to get access the value of `email` with `email = self.fields.get('email', False)`,  which is supposed to be something like `test@test.com`, but I got `<django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0x7f9b3b7abf10>`. Is it because the space is not used yet? Otherwise, how could I get the value of `email`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to get data from a form is to first call `.is_valid()`, then look up the value in `self.cleaned_data`, in this case, you'd do:

```
if self.is_valid():
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
```

For more information, see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#field-data).